# Join operation does not return any matching records if the join table contains "coded value domains"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, domains

I have a point feature class and performed a join operation against a destination table with two fields containing coded value domains defined in the same file geodatabase. Another field called "LocationId" matches a field called the same "LocationId" in the source feature class. Both fields in the their respective tables are with the same field type (Long Int) as well as other settings.

The join is not on the "domain" field in the join table.

I know there should be one matching row in the resulted feature class as I made up the values. However, when the "join" command was run, it returned no matching rows at all. When I got rid of those two fields (of coded value domains) from the destination table, the "join" worked with one row returned.

Is there anything I did wrong? Or "domains" just don't work with "join"?

The domains are of coded value. What I did was:

```
1. Create two coded value domains [Height] (coded value 0, 10, ..., 200) and [Curing] (coded value 0, 10, ..., 100)
2. Create a feature class containing fields LocationId (long int), LocationDesc, blah blah
3. Create a native table containing fields LocationId (long int), Height (in short int and Height domain) and Curing (in short int and Curing domain)
4. Add the FC to ArcMap, and run Joins and Relates > Join...
   Select the FC as source table; select the native table as the table to join the source table; select "LocationId" as the field the join is based on.
5. Run "Validate Run" and it returns no matching records.
```

Comment: Thanks. But as indicated in the edits, the join is not on the field with the domain type, but a simple integer type field.